# how to retrieve value from the mongodb using spring frame work

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongodb-java, spring-data-mongodb

how to retrieve the value from the mongodb using springframe work , can anyone share the code or tell the procedure .

and how to put the values comes from the database store them in a csv file.
Thanks
Navneet

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [MongoOperations](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoOperations.html)  interface implemented by [MongoTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html) to perform all your common database operations, including but not limited to:

- [List find(Query query,
             Class entityClass)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoOperations.html#find%28org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query,%20java.lang.Class%29)
- [void insert(Collection batchToSave,
        Class entityClass)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoOperations.html#insert%28java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.Class%29)
- [void remove(Object object)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoOperations.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29)